# Expanding animation on view with Nine-Patch as background

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I'm trying to create an animation that expands a `View` from top to bottom.

**Like this:**
[image]

I can't use a `ScaleAnimation` with `pivotY` set to 0 because this stretches the Nine-Patch like a normal `Bitmap`. I need to modify the height of my `View`.

---

**My current solution:** (`test` is the View reference)

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(test.getMeasuredHeight(), 800);
anim.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = test.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        test.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
anim.setDuration(250).start();
```

---

This works perfectly, but it expands the view to both sides:

[image]

Does anyone know a way to create such animation? **Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to keep your implementation but limit the expansion to bottom by having an element above that won't let your view grow up:

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
         ...
         android:layout_height="100dp"/> //assuming your view starts 100dps from top

    <YourView
         ...
         .../>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Since your container is a LinearLayout and the first View(FrameLayout) is 100dp height and above the view you wish to expand, it won't expand it's Height up because it can't overlap an element of the same hierarchy, so it will expand down

It also works if you use RelativeLayout by adding `android:below="@id/framelayout_id"` to YourView which will also guarantee that YourView doesn't expand up

Comment: Thanks! This solution also works with ConstraintLayout.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem as it apparently did

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra variable that holds initial position on Y axis.

**expands top**

```
 public void expandTop(final View test) {
        final float bottomAnchor = test.getY() + test.getHeight();
        final ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(test.getMeasuredHeight(), 800);

        anim.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = test.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                test.setY(bottomAnchor - (int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                test.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
        anim.setDuration(2500).start();
    }
```

**expandBottom**

```
public void expandBottom(final View test) {
    final float topAnchor = test.getY();
    final ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(test.getMeasuredHeight(), 800);

    anim.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = test.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            test.setY(topAnchor);
            test.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(2500).start();
}
```